# PowerShell - Remotely Run Windows Commands

Tags: powershell

We have a lab of computers setup in a workgroup.  They are running Windows 7.  I am trying to figure out a way to use PowerShell to run a Windows command on these machines.  My question is more specifically around how can I access these machines remotely given that they are part of a workgroup and not our domain? We don't have remote PowerShell access set up yet and I haven't really used it either.  I was thinking of WMI, but wasn't sure how I could do this given they aren't part of our domain.  If someone could point me to some code that could run something like hostname, ping, ipconfig on a remote machine in a work group that would be great!  Specifically we are trying to set the KMS server for our lab machines using: slmgr.vbs /skms 192.168.5.10

Thanks!
Seag33k

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can authenticate machine to machine using NTLM as long as your NTLM settings between the machines are set to negotiate to a compatible version. I recommend using NTLMv2. All you have to do is create users with the exact same username/password and when they match, you'll be able to authenticate to the remote machine. Here's a way to remotely start a process with WMI:

```
(Invoke-WmiMethod Win32_Process Create calc.exe -ComputerName storage1).ReturnValue -eq 0
```

Another example using explicit credentials. This doesn't require you running it as a matching user account as you can just specify the credential to use.

```
$c = get-credential
Invoke-WmiMethod -Class Win32_Process -Name Create -ArgumentList 'slmgr.vbs /skms 192.168.5.10' -EnableAllPrivileges -ComputerName MyComputerName -Credential $c
```